# Django request is launched automatically

Tags: django

I'm getting a little issue and I don't remember the way to solve my problem.

I have a template which let to query database and get a result according to user's criteria.

My view looks like :

```
@login_required
def Identity_Individu_Researching(request) :

    query_lastname_ID = request.GET.get('q1ID')
    query_firstname_ID = request.GET.get('q1bisID')
    query_naissance_ID = request.GET.get('q1terID')

    sort_params = {}

    set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'id__gt', query_lastname_ID)
    set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'Prenom__icontains', query_firstname_ID)
    set_if_not_none(sort_params, 'VilleNaissance', query_naissance_ID)

    query_ID_list = Individu.objects.filter(**sort_params) 

    return render(request, 'Identity_Individu_Recherche.html', context)
```

But this request is launched automatically when the template is loaded.

In my HTML template, I have :

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="GET" action="">
            <input type="text"  name="q1ID" placeholder="Nom (ex:TEST) " value="{{ request.GET.q1ID }}"> et
            <input type="text"  name="q1bisID" placeholder="Prénom (ex:Test)" value="{{ request.GET.q1bisID }}"> &nbsp;
            <input type="text"  name="q1terID" placeholder="Ville Naissance" value="{{ request.GET.q1terID }}"> (optionnel)
            <input class="button" type="submit" name="recherche" value="Rechercher">&nbsp;
        </form>

        <br></br>

        <table style="width:120%">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th>ID</th>
                    <th>État</th>
                    <th>N° Identification</th>
                    <th>Civilité</th>
                    <th>Nom</th>
                    <th>Prénom</th>
                    <th>Date de Naissance</th>
                    <th>Ville de Naissance</th>
                    <th>Pays de Naissance</th>
                    <th>Institution</th>
                </tr>
                {% for item in query_ID_list %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ item.id}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Etat}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.NumeroIdentification}}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Civilite }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Nom }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.Prenom }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.DateNaissance }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.VilleNaissance }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.PaysNaissance }}</td>
                    <td>{{ item.InformationsInstitution }}</td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

So How I can launch the queryset only if user submit the form with the form button ? I know it's based on `name = "jhjh"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if the request contains the form data.

```
if 'recherche' in request.GET:
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change method for your form in template

```
<form autocomplete="off" method="POST" action="">
<!--                             ^^^^^        -->
```

in the view:

```
query_ID_list = Individu.objects.all()
if request.method == 'POST':
    # your logic
    query_ID_list = query_ID_list.filter(**sort_params)

return render(request, 'Identity_Individu_Recherche.html', context)
```

Comment: POST isn't usually appropriate for search forms.